# pam / ad issue with cron

Tags: 16.04, pam, active-directory

Jobs in `/etc/crontab` which belong to non-local users now fail.  That is a bit of a problem for us:

```
May 26 13:05:01 machineXYZ CRON[26927]: pam_sss(cron:account): \
                Access denied for user abcdef: 6 (Permission denied)
```

Is anybody else seeing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777300/pam-ad-issues-with-server-based-application) is applicable here too.  With the line

```
ad_gpo_map_interactive = +unity, +polkit-1, +cron
```

we get screensaver / lockscreen as well as cron working.